# Adding overlay on video

Tags: ios, avasset

I am adding the overlay to the video and share on Facebook and whatsaap. but the quality of video becomes so poor specially on whatsapp whereas other without overlay there is best quality. Code for editing overlay the video with overlay  :

```
AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:outputFileURL options:nil];
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo  preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioComposition = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
AVAssetTrack *sourceAudioTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];

[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)
                               ofTrack:clipVideoTrack
                                atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
[audioComposition insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:sourceAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil]; //[asset duration]

[compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];

AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mixComposition duration]);
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];

//*****************//
UIImageOrientation videoAssetOrientation_;// = UIImageOrientationUp;
BOOL isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
CGAffineTransform videoTransform = clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform;

if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationRight;
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == -1.0 && videoTransform.c == 1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
   videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft;
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if (videoTransform.a == 1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == 1.0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = NO;
}
if (videoTransform.a == -1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == -1.0) {
   videoAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = NO;
}
[layerInstruction setTransform:clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
[layerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:videoAsset.duration];
//*****************//
CGSize naturalSize;
if(isVideoAssetPortrait_){
    naturalSize = CGSizeMake(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width);
} else {
    naturalSize = clipVideoTrack.naturalSize;
}


UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"overlay.png"];
CALayer *aLayer = [CALayer layer];
if (naturalSize.width > 359) {
    aLayer.frame = CGRectMake((naturalSize.width-340)/2, 0, 340, 90);

}
 else if (naturalSize.width > 200) {
     aLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, naturalSize.width-20, 65);
}
else{
     aLayer.frame = CGRectMake(15, 0, naturalSize.width-30, 60);

}
aLayer.contents = (id)myImage.CGImage;
//Needed for proper display. We are using the app icon (57x57). If you use 0,0 you will not see it
// aLayer.opacity = 1.0; //Feel free to alter the alpha here

aLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
[aLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
// CGSize videoSize = [videoAsset naturalSize];
CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];


//NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[urlsOfVideos objectAtIndex:self.pageControl.currentPage]];

 NSLog(@"videoSize ++++: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(naturalSize));
AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComp = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition] ;

float renderWidth, renderHeight;
renderWidth = naturalSize.width;
renderHeight = naturalSize.height;
videoComp.renderSize = CGSizeMake(renderWidth, renderHeight);
videoComp.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:instruction];
videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);


videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, naturalSize.width, naturalSize.height);
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, naturalSize.width, naturalSize.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:aLayer];

videoComp.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

/// instruction

instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];
videoComp.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];

assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];

assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl;
assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
assetExport.videoComposition = videoComp;

//[strRecordedFilename setString: exportPath];

[assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(void ) {
     switch (assetExport.status) {
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:{
             NSLog(@"Fail");
             NSLog(@"asset export fail error : %@", assetExport.error);

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                            {

                            });

             break;
         }
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:{
             NSLog(@"Success");

                              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                            {

                            });


             break;
         }

         default:
             break;
     }

 }       
 ];   
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to add overlay on video:

```
CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
UIImage *overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"overlay.png"];
[overlayLayer setContents:(id)[overlayImage CGImage]];
overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

//Set Up the Parent Layer
CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];
```

Have a look at the following link containig good tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Comment: I did the same. Please check

Comment: Have you gone through the link which I have given?

Comment: yes. and also download the project and share video on whatsaap, but same thing happened(i.e poor quality of video).